# SQL Server UDF, load and use it 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know we can use functions in SQL Server, but my question here:

If I write a udf, do I have to use something 'visual basic', or something, could you please provide a simple example, how to load that function, because if it is a simple function is enough to execute it, but if it uses vb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Server UDF (User Defined Functions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx) are usually written in TSQL, but they can also be written using the [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254508.aspx).

A typical use of a CLR Function or Stored Procedure is for string manipulation (which TSQL wasn't really designed for and only has limited functionality built-in)